# char Array to String and put dots between characters

Tags: java

```
public static String arrayToString(char[] array) {
            String newstring = new String(array);
            for(int c=0; c<array.length; c++) 
                }
            }
            return newstring;
```

I want to change my char Array to String and do for example ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ---> a.b.c.d
I don't know how to put dots between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are clearly a beginner, let's avoid using Java 8 streams.

```
int dotCount = array.length -1;
char[] newArray = new char[array.length + dotCount];

// copy the characters 
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  newArray[2*index] = array[index];
}

// fill the dots
for(int dotIndex = 0; dotIndex < dotCount; dotIndex++) {
  newArray[2* dotIndex + 1] = '.';
}

return new String(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (This is utilizing java 8 streams):

```
public static String arrayToString(char[] array, String delimiter) {
  String newstring = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                                    .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(array[i]))
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
  return newstring;
}
```

Then in your method call:

```
char[] array = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
String fmtString = arrayToString(array, ".");
```

The output would then be:
`a.b.c.d`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use Java version < 8, or simply don't want to use Streams you could do something like this:

```
    public static String arrayToString(char[] array) {
        StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
        int arrayLength = array.length;

        for(int c = 0; c < arrayLength - 1; c++) {
            char nextCharacter = array[c];
            newstring.append(nextCharacter);
            newstring.append('.');
        }

        if (arrayLength > 0) {
            char lastCharacter = array[arrayLength - 1];
            newstring.append(lastCharacter);
        }

        return newstring.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is using an enhanced `for` loop, with `StringBuilder`, though you can do this with `String` as well, however, when appending to a `String` in a loop, you typically should `StringBuilder` instead:

```
public static String arrayToString(char[] array) 
{
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : array) {
          sb.append(c);
          sb.append('.');
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

The `if (array.length == 0)` is used for the case when an empty array is passed.

This works by appending each character with the delimiter of `.` each iteration, and removing the final character in the `return` which would be an extra delimiter that is not needed.

**Test Run:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    char[] array = new char[]{'a','b','c'};
    System.out.println(arrayToString(array));
}
```

**Output:**

> a.b.c

Answer (score 0):

Other aproche:

```java
char[] array = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
System.out.println(
        Stream.of(new String(array).split(""))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("."))
);
```